# When do you resolve a spell with a casting time of 1 action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, spellcasting

I think I've read somewhere that spells that cost 1 action to cast are resolved in the beginning of your next turn and you make any sort of attack roll then. But I'm not so sure of it and I couldn't find a definitive answer in the *Player's Handbook*.

When does the spell resolve if its casting time is 1 action? And when do you make the roll for any effect it makes?

I would like your source on the answer to this so I can reference it in the future as well.

Comment: You're likely confusing 5E with prior editions. In 3.X, there were action spells, and "full round action" spells. The later behaved as you describe.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the PHB?  Have you taken the opportunity to [download the Free  Basic Rules](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules) from WoTC's website?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A spell with a casting time of 1 Action takes no longer to perform than a Weapon Attack.

On your turn, you can take one Action. Example Actions are Attack, Cast a Spell, Dash, etc.

In the Cast a Spell section it specifies

> Most spells do have a casting time of 1 action, so a spellcaster often uses his or her action in combat to cast such a spell.

So, if you cast a spell with a casting time of 1 Action, you resolve it the exact same way that you would resolve an attack. You declare that you are casting the spell, then you (and your target) immediately make any dice rolls necessary to resolve the outcome of the spell.

Some spells have repetitive effects once they are cast, and all of them clearly specify when those repeating effects occur.